# can't see visuals in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, roslaunch

if someone can help me , i am only seeing the frames and joint of my robot but i cant see the visuals [image]

[image]

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... copy the text from the terminal and paste it into your question instead

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possible reasons:

1. You need to add RobotModel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > Scroll down to RobotModel)
2. Make sure you've included the correct path to the model in your URDF